# Swift ios best practise for global constant

Tags: ios, swift

I need a way to change URL's through out my app in a single place.

Right now I am doing this:

```
NSLocalizedString("urls.url", comment: "")

Alamofire.request(NSLocalizedString("urls.url", comment: ""), method: .put, parameters: updateParams, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
```

But what other ways is there to do it?

Comment: To do what, precisely? And what does NSLocalizedString have to do with the matter?

Comment: @matt I want to be able to change all urls through out my app by making a change in a single file. Right now I only have to change "urls.url" to whatever url I want, then all my urls will be updated. But this is a NSLocalizedString which should be used for laungish localization and not url and such. So is there a other way to do it?

Comment: (1) Could you give a specific example of some of these urls, what they are to start with and what they would be changed to? (2) You do understand that what you're proposing will involve recompiling the app? So there is no advantage over just doing a global find-and-replace.

Comment: You can put these constants into a Swift file and access them using `Class.constantA`.